# Using a python method in a class to check variables are the same in another class object

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, methods

I have 2 files which I am using python class methods to parse data from and create sql INSERT statements. In both of my files I have a list of gene names. The first file is a simple list of 20 gene names with a panel name that is always the same. The second file has more information about the genes, and there will be multiple entries of each gene name.

my code at the moment looks like:

```
class Gene(object):

    def __init__(self, gene):
        self.gene = gene

    def make_gene_sql(self):
        sql = """INSERT INTO gene ("""+"'"+self.gene+"', '"+panel+"')"
        return sql


class Variants(object):

    def __init__(self, gene, run_id, sample, variant):
        self.run_id = run_id
        self.sample = sample
        self.gene = gene
        self.variant = variant

    def make_vsr_sql(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO variants_sample_run ("+ "'"+self.sample +"', '"+self.gene +"', '"+self.variant +"', '"+self.run_id+"')"
        return sql



gene_file = open(gene_path, 'r+')
for line in gene_file:
    gene_object = Gene(line.strip('\r\n'))
    gene_sql = gene_object.make_gene_sql()
    cursor.execute(gene_sql)


var_file = open(var_path, 'r+')
for line in var_file.readlines()[1:]:
    item = line.split('\t')
    sample = item[0]
    run = item[1]
    gene = item[2]
    variant = item[3]
    variants_object = Variants(gene, run, sample, variant)
    sql = variants_object.make_var_sql()
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

My question is: Is there a way I can make the Variants class inherit from the Gene class, and create a new function to check whether the gene variable in my variants_object is in the genes_object? I.e pass my variables through the gene class to make sure that the gene variable from my var_file is definitely in the gene file? Something like this (but actually works!)?

```
class Variants(Gene):

    def __init__(self, gene, run_id, sample, variant):
        self.run_id = run_id
        self.sample = sample
        self.gene = gene.gene
        self.variant = variant

    def check_gene(gene):
        if self.gene not in gene.gene:
            print('Gene not correct')

    def make_vsr_sql(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO variants_sample_run ("+ "'"+self.sample +"', '"+self.gene +"', '"+self.variant +"', '"+self.run_id+"')"
        return sql
```

I was thinking this could perhaps use a list created from the Gene class containing all of the genes, however I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think inheritance can help you with this one. You can try to make a class variable for all `Gene`:

```
class Gene(object):
    # The class variable that keeps track of all genes
    genes = []    

    def __init__(self, gene):
        Gene.genes.append(gene)
        self.gene = gene
```

And your `Variants` class:

```
class Variants(Gene):
    def __init__(self, gene, run_id, sample, variant):
        self.run_id = run_id
        self.sample = sample
        self.gene = gene
        self.variant = variant

    def check_gene(gene):
        if self.gene not in Gene.gene:
            print('Gene not correct')
```

Answer (score 0):

class Variants(Gene):

```
def __init__(self, gene, run_id, sample, variant):
    self.run_id = run_id
    self.sample = sample
    self.gene = gene.gene
    self.variant = variant

def check_gene(gene):
    if self.gene not in gene.gene:
        print('Gene not correct')
```

Comment: i will try another one

Comment: Explain how this can solve problem. Add some details.